# Wordpress Data base Plugin

Tags: database, wordpress

*This is not really a programming question. On wordpress front-end I have a custom made form. I want to store the form entries in a database table on wordpress back-end. Is there any way(plugin) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert data into a database table, it is a best practice to use `$wpdb`. The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb) can provide you with examples and more information to help you proceed.

It's exactly the same as a normal MySQL query using PHP only you're using the **wpdb** class for some PHP variables. Just output your query string which uses **wpdb**. If it looks like a normal MySQL query that would work, then it will work with the wpdb.

Comment: _@Franklin Thanks for your help, But I want to store the values in a seperate database table in wordpress. I wonder did ["Formidable WordPress Plugin"](http://devilmustcry.com/blog/formidable-wordpress-plugin-to-create-database-forms.html) will work for this?._

Comment: @cherry If this table is in same database as your WordPress installation you can use $wpdb to get data from it. Otherwise you can instantiate your own wpdb object with connection details for other database.